# Getting an error in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a small web app where I will show a chart of the top 10 popular TV shows. Then, When I go to the browser and inspect I get an error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/unpr?p0=showProvider%20%3C-%20show%20%3C-%20MainController

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Angular JS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="Top10App">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="container">
        10
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="content">


      <!--TODO: Loop through shows and display each one with this HTML-->
      <!--ng-repeat="show in shows" -->
          <div>
            <div class="rank">{{$index + 1}}</div>

            <h2 class="series"> {{ index.series }}</h2>
            <p class="genre">{{ index.genre }} </p>
            <p class="run-start"> {{ index.run_start }}</p>
            <p class="description"> {{ index.description }} </p>

         </div>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>




    <!-- Modules -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>

    <!-- Services -->
    <script src="js/services/show.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

> MainController.js

```
    app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'show', function ($scope, show) {


show.success(function(data) {

$scope.show = data;


});




}]);
```

**show.js**

```
    app.factory('Top10App', ['$http', function($http){
  return $http.get('shows.json')
  .success(function(data){
    return data;
  })
  .error(function(err){
    return err;
  });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're defining your service name as 'Top10App', so that's the way you should access it, not by the file name.

```
['$scope', 'Top10App', function ($scope, Top10App) { ...

  Top10App.success(...
```

Comment: also, in my index.html should I change {{index.series }} to {{ Top10app.series }}

Comment: Sure. Or if you want to still use "show" as the name of your service, change the declaration at "...factory('Top10App')" to "...factory('show')".

Comment: Actually, I've read it wrong. Sorry. No, you should still use the index, unless you change the variable name. The service name doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: Okay.. But now, in the browser it shows the number one, not the data from "shows.json"?

Answer (score 0):

First, do you created the module? You should has something like:

```
// app.js
angular.module('app', []);

// maincontroller.js
angular.module('app').controller('myController, ...', [.......]);

// factory.js
angular.module('app').factory(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to inject show as a dependency for your controller, but it doesn't look like that is defined anywhere. That's why your error is telling you that it's an unknown provider.

I'm guessing you're trying to use your `Top10App` factory, so you need to inject it as such

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'Top10App', function ($scope, Top10App) {
  Top10App.success(...)
}
```